# To Invoke Mutual SSL Enabled endpoint in WSO2 EI 6.4.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator, mutual-authentication

I am trying Mutual SSL in WSo2 EI by following exact steps mentioned in this [blog](https://medium.com/@eranda/ssl-notes-configuring-mutual-ssl-on-wso2-ei-esb-with-backend-servers-f9e7a0c311d2)

WSO2 EI acts as `client` and Axis2server is `backend`

All Pre-requisites mentioned in this [blog](https://medium.com/@eranda/ssl-notes-configuring-mutual-ssl-on-wso2-ei-esb-with-backend-servers-f9e7a0c311d2) done and detailed steps are [in another raised questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75912813/mutual-ssl-in-wso2-ei-6-5-0-filenotfoundexception-could-not-load-customsslpr).

- Axis2Server started
- WSO2 EI Server Started

Pass through Proxy Service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="SSLStockQuoteProxy"
       startOnLoad="true"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       transports="http,https">
   <target>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
      <endpoint>
         <address uri="https://axis2.backend.mytest:9002/services/SimpleStockQuoteService"/>
      </endpoint>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

Invoke the `SSLStockQuoteProxy` service using a axis2 client

Executed below command at `<EI_HOME>/samples/axis2Client/` directory

```
C:\mutualssl\wso2axis2-6.4.0\wso2ei-6.4.0\samples\axis2Client>ant stockquote -Daddurl=http://localhost:8280/services/SSLStockQuoteProxy
```

The above command gives me result like below in same `axis2 client`

[image: result]

My Concern here is that if i invoke this proxy service via `Try this Service` tool below ERROR response i got.

[image: proxy call]

I tested via API calls also.

API Code:

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="mutualsslapi" context="/mutualsslapi">
   <resource methods="GET">
      <inSequence>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="INFO:" value="Hit received in Mutualssl API"/>
         </log>
         <call>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="https://axis2.backend.mytest:9002/services/SimpleStockQuoteService"/>
            </endpoint>
         </call>
         <respond/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence/>
      <faultSequence>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="ERROR_MESSAGE:::: " expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')"/>
         </log>
         <makefault version="soap11">
            <code xmlns:soap11Env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" value="soap11Env:Client"/>
            <reason expression="$ctx:ERROR_MESSAGE"/>
            <role/>
         </makefault>
         <send/>
      </faultSequence>
   </resource>
</api>
```

API Hit via postman:
[image: postman]

WSO2 Logs:

```
[2023-04-05 22:11:00,948] []  INFO - LogMediator INFO: = Hit received in Mutualssl API
```

Apart from this, nothing printed in Logs when I invoke above mentioned API.

If mutual SSL is enabled, then that mutual ssl enabled endpoint (axis2 services ) call should happen right?

How to Test this Mutual SSL Flow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the call should go through if you have all the certificates in place. Your issue is you are not sending the correct Payload or the correct SOAPAction with the request. Which is mandatory if you are doing Soap calls. You can add the correct SOAP header like below before doing the call. Also make sure you send a proper payload to the backend.

```xml
<header name="Action" value="urn:getQuote" />
```

Comment: Hi @ycr,
Thanks for response. Not sure on which SOAP Action i need to pass to backend. I tried with above shared Action ie (urn:getQuote) before endpoint call, But getting same ERROR Response. But in Axis2client getting stock prize as $75 which is attached in question already. Do you have any other suggestion to test this Mutual SSL flow?

Comment: @Justin I would suggest, isolating the backend first, use SOAPUI(You can use the wsdl of the service https://axis2.backend.mytest:9002/services/SimpleStockQuoteService?wsdl) or Postman to test it directly. Then figure out the exact Headers and the content you need to pass. Once you figure out the payload, try proxying it through EI.

Answer (score 0):

As per suggestion given by @ycr, I have tried the above mentioned `Axis2Service` in `SOAP UI`

Axis2 backend WSDL URL: (`wsdl accessed via http not https`) http://axis2.backend.mytest:9000/services/SimpleStockQuoteService?wsdl

Sample Request mentioned below found from [this blog](https://medium.com/think-integration/developing-a-simple-message-using-wso2-payload-factory-mediator-8379abfeeb30) or [wso2 doc](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/Using+the+Sample+Clients)

```
<m:getQuote xmlns:m="http://services.samples/xsd">
    <m:request>
        <m:symbol>IBM</m:symbol>
    </m:request>
</m:getQuote>
```

SOAP Action:

```
<header name="Action" scope="default" value="urn:getQuote"/>
```

via SOAP UI:

[image: SOAP UI]

`SSLStockQuoteProxy` via `try this service tool`:

[image: proxy]

Remodified API code:

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="mutualsslapi" context="/mutualsslapi">
   <resource methods="POST">
      <inSequence>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="INFO:" value="Hit received in Mutualssl API"/>
         </log>
         <property name="companyName" expression="json-eval($.companyName)" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
         <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>
               <m0:getQuote xmlns:m0="http://services.samples">
                  <m0:request>
                     <m0:symbol>$1</m0:symbol>
                  </m0:request>
               </m0:getQuote>
            </format>
            <args>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('companyName')"/>
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>
         <header name="Action" scope="default" value="urn:getQuote"/>
         <call>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="https://axis2.backend.mytest:9002/services/SimpleStockQuoteService"/>
            </endpoint>
         </call>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="RESPOSNE::::: " expression="$body"/>
         </log>
         <respond/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence/>
      <faultSequence>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="ERROR_MESSAGE:::: " expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')"/>
         </log>
         <makefault version="soap11">
            <code xmlns:soap11Env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" value="soap11Env:Client"/>
            <reason expression="$ctx:ERROR_MESSAGE"/>
            <role/>
         </makefault>
         <send/>
      </faultSequence>
   </resource>
</api>
```

via postman(API hit):

[image: API hit]